# Issues with Multiroot to solve simultaneous equations in R

Tags: r

I now have issues while using `multiroot`. I am not able to find out what the issue is, though the syntax and the way I have implemented looks correct when I compare it with the documentation. Kindly suggest.
My code is below:

```
n <- 128
tn <- 28712
sumTc <- 784321
sumT <- 42382
model <- function(b,c){
  c( 1/b -(tn^c)/(exp(b*(tn^c))-1),  1/c -(b*(tn^c))/(exp(b*(t^c))-1)+sum(log(tVec)/n))
}

multiroot(model, start=c(0.00004,1))
```

This gives me an error, which says `Error in f(x, ...) : argument "c" is missing, with no default`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a vector, as a parameter to a function:

```
model <- function(x) {
  c(
    1/x[1] -(tn^x[2])/(exp(x[1]*(tn^x[2]))-1) - sumTc/n,  1/x[2] -(x[1]*(tn^x[2]))/(exp(x[1]*(tn^x[2]))-1)+sum(log(tVec)/n) +(x[1]*sum((tVec^x[2])*log(tVec))/n)
  )
}
```

So, `b` and `c` are now in a vector as `x[1]` and `x[2]`.

Comment: @VIDHYASHREE If it solves your problem, the best would be to mark the question as a solution.

Comment: I am not sure how to mark this comment as an answer.

Comment: @VIDHYASHREE There is a tick mark on the right for this. Also, see the [quick tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), there is an overview of StackOverflow community.